# Release build for Visual Studio Cordova Project failes

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, visual-studio-cordova

I am using visual studio 2015 with update 3 and TACO Update 10. Everything was working fine, but since yesterday I'm unable to make a release build for android. I reinstalled almost everything on my machine and the problem continues. The error has something to do with the gradle daemon. The relevant part of the build output is:

```
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
**1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Unable to start the daemon process.**
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.13/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Please read the following process output to find out more:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : -----------------------
**1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component**
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClasspathUtil.getClasspathForClass(ClasspathUtil.java:68)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.internal.installation.CurrentGradleInstallationLocator.findDistDir(CurrentGradleInstallationLocator.java:54)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.internal.installation.CurrentGradleInstallationLocator.locateViaClass(CurrentGradleInstallationLocator.java:45)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.internal.installation.CurrentGradleInstallationLocator.locateViaClassLoader(CurrentGradleInstallationLocator.java:41)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.internal.installation.CurrentGradleInstallationLocator.locate(CurrentGradleInstallationLocator.java:31)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.internal.installation.CurrentGradleInstallation.locate(CurrentGradleInstallation.java:46)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.internal.installation.CurrentGradleInstallation.get(CurrentGradleInstallation.java:41)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:45)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon.main(GradleDaemon.java:22)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

Comment: Try deleting  `.gradle` directory from `C:\Users\<username>`.

Comment: I tried it already with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing VS TACO to use the latest version of JAVA JDK fixed the problem.